# How to change Panel background color in Python VCL GUI app

Tags: python, user-interface, vcl

I'm using the [DelphiVCL GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiVCL4Python) and trying to change the background color on a `Panel` component, but it's not working

I have the following code to create the `Form` and the `Panel` on my Form:

```
from delphivcl import *

class frmMain(Form):

    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "poScreenCenter"

        self.myPanel = Panel(self)
        self.myPanel.Parent = self
        self.myPanel.Align = "alClient"
        
        self.myPanel.AlignWithMargins = True
        self.myPanel.Margins.Top = 100
        self.myPanel.Margins.Right = 100
        self.myPanel.Margins.Bottom = 100
        self.myPanel.Margins.Left = 100

        self.myPanel.Caption = "Hello World!"
        self.myPanel.Font.Size = 30
        self.myPanel.Color = "$00D2E525" # Aqua Color
```

I'm trying to give it an Aqua background color ($00D2E525). My output Form then looks like this:
[image: Python GUI VCL Hello World App]

My "Hello World!" Panel should have the aqua background color on it, but it's not showing. I'm setting the background color with this piece of code:

```
self.myPanel.Color = "$00D2E525"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. After playing with the code for a bit, I realized that I needed to add the following line of code in order to make sure the Panel is using the `Color` property:

```
self.myPanel.StyleElements = ""
```

After adding that line of code, my Panel now works and shows correctly:

[image: Python GUI Hello World]

If you don't clear the `StyleElements` property, then the Style Manager will handle things like the `Color` property. So you need to clear it if you want to set your own color. So my full code now looks like this and works:

```
from delphivcl import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "poScreenCenter"

        self.myPanel = Panel(self)
        self.myPanel.Parent = self
        self.myPanel.Align = "alClient"

        self.myPanel.AlignWithMargins = True
        self.myPanel.Margins.Top = 100
        self.myPanel.Margins.Right = 100
        self.myPanel.Margins.Bottom = 100
        self.myPanel.Margins.Left = 100
 
        self.myPanel.Caption = "Hello World!"
        self.myPanel.Font.Size = 30
        self.myPanel.StyleElements = ""
        self.myPanel.Color = "$00D2E525"

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = 'Hello World'
    MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    MainForm.Show()
    FreeConsole()
    Application.Run()


main()
```