# How to change GroupBox background color in Python VCL GUI app

Tags: python, user-interface, vcl

I'm using the [DelphiVCL GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiVCL4Python) and trying to change the background color on a `GroupBox` component, but it's not working

I have the following code to create the `Form` and the `GroupBox` on my Form:

```
from delphivcl import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
    
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "poScreenCenter"

        self.myGroupBox = GroupBox(self)
        self.myGroupBox.Parent = self
        self.myGroupBox.Align = "alClient"
        self.myGroupBox.Caption = "Hello World!"
        self.myGroupBox.Font.Size = 30

        self.myGroupBox.AlignWithMargins = True
        self.myGroupBox.Margins.Top = 100
        self.myGroupBox.Margins.Right = 100
        self.myGroupBox.Margins.Bottom = 100
        self.myGroupBox.Margins.Left = 100

        self.myGroupBox.StyleElements = ""
        self.myGroupBox.Color = "$00418964" # Green Color
```

I'm trying to give it a Green background color ($00418964). I have the `StyleElements` cleared like mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75581205/2908017):

```
self.myGroupBox.StyleElements = ""
```

But even with `StyleElements` cleared, it still isn't working. My output Form then looks like this:

[image: Python GUI app with Hello World GroupBox]

My "Hello World!" GroupBox should have the green background color on it, but it's not showing. I'm setting the background color with this piece of code:

```
self.myGroupBox.Color = "$00418964"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. After playing with the code for a bit, I realized that I needed to add the following line of code in order to make sure the `GroupBox` is using the `Color` property:

```
self.myGroupBox.ParentBackground = False
```

After adding that line of code, my GroupBox now works and shows correctly:

[image: Python GUI app with Hello World Green GroupBox]

Clearing the `StyleElements` property is irrelevant. The color changes no matter what the property is set to. It's a bit weird and inconsistent with how the `Panel` works with background color in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75581205/2908017), but at least setting `ParentBackground` to `False` allows me to change the Color of the GroupBox. So my full code now looks like this and works:

```
from delphivcl import *

class frmMain(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
    
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "poScreenCenter"

        self.myGroupBox = GroupBox(self)
        self.myGroupBox.Parent = self
        self.myGroupBox.Align = "alClient"
        self.myGroupBox.Caption = "Hello World!"
        self.myGroupBox.Font.Size = 30

        self.myGroupBox.AlignWithMargins = True
        self.myGroupBox.Margins.Top = 100
        self.myGroupBox.Margins.Right = 100
        self.myGroupBox.Margins.Bottom = 100
        self.myGroupBox.Margins.Left = 100

        self.myGroupBox.ParentBackground = False
        self.myGroupBox.Color = "$00418964"

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = 'Hello World'
    Application.MainFormOnTaskBar = True 
    MainForm = frmMain(Application)
    MainForm.Show()
    FreeConsole()
    Application.Run()


main()
```